# Can't get SQL Mapper's copyfrom() method to work in Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to get [copyfrom](http://fatfreeframework.com/sql-mapper#copyfrom) to work in a PHP application I am developing.

Here is the function attached to my PUT /api/visitor/@id route:

```
public function update($f3, $params) {

    $data = json_decode( $f3->get('BODY'), true );

    $visitor_id = $params['id'];
    $visitor = new \Models\Visitor();

    $visitor->load(array('id = ?', $visitor_id));

    // if mapper object is hydrated copy from request body
    if(!$visitor->dry()) {
      $visitor->copyFrom($data);
    }   

    $visitor->save();
}
```

My visitor model extends \DB\SQL\Mapper, and my $data's keys match my mapper object's properties, but $data doesn't always contain a key for every mapper object property. Does the array need to contain a key for every single mapper object property?

Anyway, the information stored in the assoc array $data does not get stored in the database.

I've also tried copyfrom() and copyFrom(). I saw both in the documentation and other examples.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the array need to contain a key for every single mapper object property?

No.

But, array inputs are only available in F3 v3.5. If you are running v3.4 or below, you need to put your data into a hive key first.

```
if(!$visitor->dry()) {
  $f3->set('data',$data);
  $visitor->copyFrom('data');
}
```

Comment: I inherited an old code base to write this new app and didn't think about it being a versioning issue. Thank you so much. I was pulling my hair out over this one.